# Basics of Facebook login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm having a hard time understanding how Facebook communicates with my server when a user logs in (after approving my facebook app). I've been looking through guides and other Stackoverflow questions for hours on end but can't seem to get the hang of it. The documentation on http://developers.facebook.com/ isn't to much help much either.

What I want to do is to have a Facebook login button on my page which opens a Facebook login window (using Facebook's Javascript SDK). When the user then logs in to Facebook and approves my app I want to get the user's data (name, email, age) and store it in my database. How do I get this data, **SECURELY** (server-side confirmation/authorization)?

Basically, in this order;

- a user clicks log-in button on my site
- a pop-up is shown where the user can log in & approve the app on Facebook
- check if user has already logged in before by getting user's user_id
- if it's the users first time logging in, the user's Facebook data (specifically: full name, picture, email adress, age) is gathered by me and stored in my database

After the user logs/approves the app in the Facebook pop-up, where is the user's data then sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user approves the app, the user's data is not sent anywhere. You need to make an API call to retrieve the data.

Facebook is an [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) provider. You use Facebook Login so the user can give you permission to access her Facebook data (such as email, friend list, messages, news feed etc). You can also get permissions to take action on behalf of the user (such as uploading a photo, posting to news feed etc.) While starting the OAuth flow, you specify which permissions you will request from the user. These are called **scopes**.

The authorization flow that happens in the pop-up window is there for the user to give you permission to access the data that you request. This permission is represented as an **access token** which you have to use everytime you want to retreive user data, or attempt to do something on behalf of the user.

Once you have the access token, you can use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) to get whatever data you want from Facebook. If you try to access some data that you did not get permission for, then the API method will return an access denied error.

I wanted to give some more links about scopes and access tokens from the Facebook Developers site but my reputation score is too low :)

Comment: So what I want to do is to send the access token, which I get using Facebook's JS SDK, to my server via, for example, an AJAX-request and then use that access token to do my registration/validation? How secure is this and how long is that access token valid?

Comment: @WillB That's about right. You can find details about access tokens on the [Facebook Developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

You make your requests using SSL so I would say they are pretty secure.

Just go over the documentation on the Facebook Developers site. It's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: It's all making sense now, I feel so stupid for not understanding it immediatly. I've been looking at it the completely wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) No need to feel bad, OAuth is a little complicated when you first get into it.

Comment: Is [this an acceptable way to do it?](http://pastebin.com/jDaL3Wmi). It seems to easy to be true.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that's the way to do it, as I haven't used the Facebook JS API before. But running the code and seeing if it works is the best way to see if it's an acceptable way don't you think :)